# How does absolutely positioned element in ie7 automatically repositions on resize/on clicking in the window?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position, absolute

Please refer the screenshot below.

Problem is : I load the page in IE7 with dev-tools open. I notice that 2 of the red triangle's towards the bottom of the page are not positioned where it should be. Once I click somewhere inside the page or close the dev-tools, these red-triangles automatically gets positioned correctly.

The red triangle is absolutely positioned. I tried `overflow:visible`, `zoom:1`, `border:1px solid transparent` thinking that it might be the IE7-redraw/repaint issue, but didn't help.

This is the [question that I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515835/how-an-absolutely-positioned-element-overlaps-the-following-next-element-without) related to the same layout.

Does anybody have any clue on this behaviour in IE7 and any ideas to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't really create more than one question for the same subject, you should instead provide bounties for more incentive.

Answer (score 0):

You should really edit you're question so we don't have to look for code in other pages, but based on the code here:

[Code from other question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515835/how-an-absolutely-positioned-element-overlaps-the-following-next-element-without)

---

### HTML

```
<body>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="c-icon-v2 c-icon-error-a"></span>
            <input type="text"   value="" id="Validation_Field1" name="Validation.Field1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="c-icon-v2 c-icon-error-a"></span>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txtarea" id="txtarea"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
.c-icon-error-a {
        height: 17px;
        width: 18px;
    }
    .c-icon-v2 {
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSjot.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 14px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 14px;
    }
    .c-icon-error-a {
        margin: 4px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    ul li {
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
```

---

You can check my updated fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/CNKsx/3/ see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldn't do that way because, sometimes that input element might not be wrapped in an <li> like that, so I can't rely on any parent element.

Comment: but does it solve the problem, if it does I will try to edit the code so it works with the input tag out of the li

Comment: Thanks again, but I didn't get the answer for my original question